# About the additonal external clock of the Atmega128

Tags: microcontroller, clock, atmega, pulse

I have some projects using the 16 bits timer/counter of an *Atmega128*,
and I finally used all bits timer/counter 1 and 3.

I need more 16 bits timer/counter, so I just thought about using the pin T1 or T2. I recognized that these PINs do exist for getting an external clock signal, don't they?

Comment: Tx pins can be used to clock an existing counter, but they do not create another extra counter. What exactly do you mean by _used every counter_? Which particular problem do you need to solve with the extra counter?

Comment: I guess you need a controller with more timer/counter!

Comment: Thanks guys, I meant that I wanted to use every timer/counter port of 16bits (Timer/counter 1,3) but I finally recognized that I can't use more timer/counter port additionally.